# unable to install react-native project

Tags: react-native

Everything was working fine but when I tried to create a new project it throws this error.
[image: error msg]

command used:

```
react-native init AppName
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
node -version :v10.15.1
npm -version :6.8.0
```

Comment: can you give more detail about your project

Comment: @ahmeturganci IDK if you saw the image, but clearly the error is when trying to create a project.

Comment: I can reproduce your error with node10 too. Can you please test it with node-v8.10 (for example) ? It should work

Comment: There was issue in the version, working fine in latest version